# Add SQLite Plugin to Phonegap 3.0 from commandline

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova

I am using Phonegap 3.0 for my latest project. I tried to add the native sqlite database plugin to prepopulate data from an existing database. The issue is i could install the plugin through commandline . It showed the following error:

```
#phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/jarlehansen/PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-iOS.git

adding the plugin:
https://github.com/jarlehansen/PhoneGap-SQLitePlugin-iOS.git

fs.js:427   return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^ Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/var/folders/7j/1qkbsztx3_bgtslq3pnnr9jc0000gn/T/plugman-tmp1383202788796/plugin.xml'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
    at Object.module.exports.parseElementtreeSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/util/xml-helpers.js:119:27)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/util/plugins.js:67:39
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/shelljs/shell.js:1707:7
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:635:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:735:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous    (child_process.js:948:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
```

I tried to manually install the plugin by importing the header files and main files and js file and then by adding feature to config.xml. But that also was a failure,.

Please Help me out to install this plugin in Phonegap 3.0

Answer (score 1):

Within Cordova you can install the plugin from remote location like this:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin.git
```

But I guess you need Git locally installed as a prerequisite. Not sure how the PhoneGap command looks like. Credits go to [here](http://www.excellentwebworld.com/integrate-sqlite-plugin-in-phonegap-for-android-and-ios/).

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to my mind when there is no such file or directory is that the directory doesn't exist because whatever tried to create it did not have proper permissions.

Try checking the permissions (this may just be a matter of running it with 'sudo')

Comment: I used sudo but same result

Answer (score 0):

It's a longshot, but i found that sometimes the install worked only when i used the cordova command line. download its bin and try the following:

```
cordova install --platform <android/ios> --project <project dir> --plugin <plugin's git>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got is solution by using this plugin https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin
which offers adding though Cordova CLI commands.